# call popBackStack result more than one times of onBackPressed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

My app has this flow

```
Activity (TabLayout) -> Fragment 1 -> Fragment 2 -> Fragment 3
```

When I either press back on Fragment 2 or Fragment 3, I already go back to Fragment 1. I want to go back to Fragment 2 if I am on Fragment 3.

From fragment 1 to fragment 2

```
Frag2 childFrag = new Frag2();
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frag2_frame, childFrag)
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();
```

From fragment 2 to fragment 3

```
Frag3 childFrag = new Frag3();
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frag3_frame, childFrag)
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();
```

onBackPressed in Activity

```
// a fragments list for tablayout
ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();    

public void onBackPressed(){
    fragments.get(selectedTab).getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding backStack

```
Frag2 childFrag = new Frag2();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frag2_frame, childFrag)
    .addToBackStack("Frag2 ")
    .commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Once fragment 1 is added to the Activity, I believe you'll need to use `getChildFragmentManager()` to add additional fragments **from a fragment**. This method is available to classes that extend a Fragment.

---

### Edit

---

As you've said you are using `getChildFragmentManager()`, I would use `.beginTransaction().replace(...)` instead of `.beginTransaction().add(...)`.

Comment: sorry. is ```getChildFragmentManager()```. EDITED. my bad

Comment: ```.replace``` also return the same result

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the deepest fragment. Then popBackStack right there.

```
List<Fragment> fs2 = fragments.get(selectedTab).getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0).getChildFragmentManager().getFragments();
FragmentManager f = fragments.get(selectedTab).getChildFragmentManager();
while (fs2.size() > 0) {
    fs2 = fs2.get(0).getChildFragmentManager().getFragments();
    f = f.getFragments().get(0).getChildFragmentManager();
}
f.popBackStack();
```